# How to watch private members of a huge Dictionary<> in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a huge Dictionary (> 1M items) instance that I want to watch its private members (capacity, etc) for debugging. When I want to watch the dictionary visual studio shows the contents of key value pairs, which is of course a huge list. It does not allow me to see the private members that I want to see as it reckons it already displayed too much of an information on the dictionary.

Do you know if there is a way to turn the default behaviour off and make VS2010 display dictionaries like any other object?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to just enter the interesting fields into the watch window.
So instead of `myDictionary` put `myDictionary.freeList` into the watch window.

You can also customize the format by writing a visualizer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2zc529c.aspx